# How to install Jenkins plugin remotely?

Tags: ssh, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to install jenkins plugins on a remote machine. I have root permission on it and I install jenkins using `yum install` now I want to install a list of plugin but I don't know how to do that.

I googled and found some website but all of the solution they provided weren't what I expected.

Comment: Have you tried opening the Jenkins web interface and going to "Manage Jenkins" --> "Manage Plugins"?

Comment: @jwernerny I know how to use web interface but what I want is to build a jenkins master automatically with a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Jenkins command line interface to install plugins from a script. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI. If this isn't what you expected, perhaps you could tell us more about what you expect.